# OneToMany association in Sequelize for GraphQL. Custom foreignKey

Tags: graphql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to create an Apollo Server for GraphQL with the help of Sequelize.

I have followed the docs of Sequelize and some Tutorials, but I still have the error:

`User.hasMany(models.Recipe);`

`Recipe.belongsTo(models.User, { foreignKey: 'userId'} );`

But when I execute a mutation in GraphQL to add a new Recipe in my database, I watch my console and it is executing the following query:

```
INSERT INTO "Recipe" ("id","title","ingredients","direction", "userId") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3) RETURNING "id","title","ingredients","direction","userId", **"UserId"**;
```

It has one more field than expected in RETURNING, what returns and error and I don't know why.

```
"message": "Doesn't exist column «UserId»",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "createRecipe"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "exception": {
          "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
          "parent": {
            "length": 242,
            "name": "error",
            "severity": "ERROR",
            "code": "42703",
            "hint": "You probably want to refer column «Recipe.userId».",
```

I know I can change the foreignKey and name it in capital letter ('UserId'), that would solve the problem, but I want to have the posibility to custom my own foreign keys.

As requested, these are my migrations:

```
await queryInterface.createTable('Recipe', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      userId: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false
      },
      title: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      ingredients: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      direction: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }
    });

await queryInterface.createTable('User', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      password: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      }
    });
```

This is de models/recipe.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Recipe = sequelize.define('Recipe', {
    title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    ingredients: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    direction: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    modelName: 'Recipe',
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: false
  });
  Recipe.associate = function(models) {
    Recipe.belongsTo(models.User);
  };
  return Recipe;
};
```

And this is the schema.js:

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server')

const typeDefs = gql`
    type Query {
        user(id: Int!): User
        allRecipes: [Recipe!]!
        recipe(id: Int!): Recipe
    }

    type User {
        id: Int!
        name: String!
        email: String!
        recipes: [Recipe!]!
      }

    type Recipe {
        id: Int!
        title: String!
        ingredients: String!
        direction: String!
        user: User!
    }

    type Mutation {
        createUser(name: String!, email: String!, password: String!): User!
        createRecipe(
          userId: Int!
          title: String!
          ingredients: String!
          direction: String!
        ): Recipe!
    }
`

module.exports = typeDefs
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show model definitions. I suppose you didn't indicate a field name while describing `userId`

Comment: @Anatoly I have edited to show the models. Is that what causes this to return userId and UserId?

Comment: You added migration but I wish to see model definitions that you use to query recipes

Comment: @Anatoly do you mean that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should indicate `foreignKey` option in `hasMany` as well:

```
User.hasMany(models.Recipe, { foreignKey: 'useId' })
```